# Взаимодействие с переменной из другого класса

Tags: objective-c

Как я могу например изменить значение переменной из другого класса?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        BOOL bIsVisible;
}
```

Как мне поменять значение bIsVisible?

Comment: Вам это нужно для того, чтобы в наследнике какого-нибудь библиотечного класса переопределить приватный метод?

Answer (score 2):

Добавим к этому делу внешний интерфейс, чтобы извне было видно то, что нам понадобится для работы. Для переменной blsVisible нам нужен метод для доступа и редактирования, а общем виде это пара методов (setter и getter)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        BOOL bIsVisible;
}
 - (void)setBlsVisible:(BOOL)aBlsVisible
 - (BOOL)blsVisible;
@end
```

соответственно в .m файле

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)setBlsVisible:(BOOL)aBlsVisible {
    blsVisible = aBlsVisible;
}

- (BOOL)blsVisible {
    return blsVisible;
}

@end
```

Или просто просим систему сделать всю эту скучную работу за нас, описав `@property`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL blsVisible;

@end
```

теперь можно получать доступ к переменной через точку

```
viewController.blsVisible = YES; //  на самом деле вызывается setBlsVisible:, в случае с @property метод генерится автоматически, так же можно написать [viewController setBlsVisible:YES];

if (viewController.blsVisible) // или [viewController blsVisible], опять же вызывается одноименный метод
```

внутри класса автоматически создается instance variable `BOOL _blsVisible;`, это означает, что внутри класса мы может получить доступ к этой переменной не только через self.blsVisible, но и через _blsVisible. Также можно задать кастомное имя этой переменной, для этого нужно чуть ниже `@implementation ViewController` описать `@synthersize blsVisible = _myCustomBoolInstanceVariableName;`

если хочется иметь красивый геттер, можно описать его например так:

```
@property (nonactomic, getter = isBlsVisible) BOOL blsVisible;
```

теперь сеттер вызывается точно также, как и описано выше, но еще появился метод

`viewController.isBlsVisible` возвращающий нам тоже самое значение, или `[viewController isBlsVisible]`

Comment: отлично описано!

Answer (score 2):

iFreeman все верно описал если отвечать именно на вопрос, но есть один смущающий меня момент в самой формулировке - зачем вам нужна данная переменная? Есть подозрение что для того чтобы определять показан или нет вид? Тогда лучше не делать отдельный булевный флаг, а пробросить свойство `self.view.hidden` наверх